# linear gradient css not working with navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap 3 in my project and I have this navbar navbar-inverse. The background color of the navbar is black because it's inverse. What I want to do is to change the background color of that navbar. I've tried this code but it isn't working.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2ebf16, #217812);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2ebf16), to(#217812));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2ebf16, #217812);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#2ebf16', EndColorStr='#217812');
}
.navbar-inverse .container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Land Tenure Services</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the non-prefixed version in your CSS rule (as the last one)

```
background: linear-gradient(center top, #2ebf16, #217812);
```

Comment: oh it just worked! yesterday when i try it there's nothing changes but now when i try it just worked.. i don't know what happened.